# ошибка в mysqli запросе

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

имеется код запроса:

```
SELECT 
    n.id, 
    n.user_id, 
    n.from_id, 
    n.message, 
    n.image, 
    n.likes, 
    n.replies, 
    n.timestamp 
FROM 
    messages AS n 
LEFT JOIN 
    subscribe AS u_s 
ON 
    u_s.subscr_id = n.user_id 
WHERE 
    (
        u_s.user_id = {$_SESSION['id']} 
    OR 
        n.user_id = {$_SESSION['id']}
    ) 
    AND 
        u_s.display = 1 {$addon} 
    AND 
        n.display  = 1  
GROUP BY 
    n.id 
ORDER BY 
    n.id 
DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

но при выполнении выдает ошибку " Column 'display' in where clause is ambiguous. ", почему? указано ведь n.display = 1 AND u_s.display = 1 , то есть дисплеи прописаны для разных таблиц

Comment: А что у вас может содержаться в переменной `$addon`?

Comment: в данном случае она null, так что дело не в ней

Comment: И - зачем Вам вторая сортировка? Сделайте `GROUP BY n.id DESC`, а секцию `ORDER BY` уберите.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте вывод указанного запроса в переменную и посмотрите ее содержимое на наличие дополнительных параметров, в идеале дебаггером или проще с помощью echo, print_r.

В какую-то переменную у вас все-таки идет вставка условия display без указания таблицы.

**Сам запрос составлен верно.**